# How can I detect when a line is automatically wrapped in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When typing text into a textarea and it becomes wider than the area, the text is wrapped onto the next line. Is there a way I can programmatically determine when this happens?

Comment: if you go over the bottom then the scrollHeight changes, but i don't think just wrapping itself does anything. i hope i'm wrong.

Comment: Thought I'd be able to use [`Range.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect), couldn't make a working example. You could try copying the `<textarea>`s value to a `<span>` which has a copy of all applied CSS and _max-width_ set to match the `<textarea>` for the word wrapping.

Answer (score 5):

There's no actual event fired when the wrapping occurs, but you can hack a solution if you know the width of the textarea.

Listen for the change event on the text area and transfer the text into a div that wraps to it's content;

```
<div class="textwidth"></div>
```

With style:

```
.textwidth {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Calculate the width of the div with the text content and compare that to the constant width of the textarea:

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
  var lastLine = $(this).val().split('/n').pop();
  var width = $('.textwidth').text(lastLine).width(); 
  if ( width >  $('textarea').width() ) {
    // fire wrap event
  }
});
```

Here's a bit of a shoddy fiddle that should give you some idea how to continue: http://jsfiddle.net/cXbAh/1/

Comment: This seems like it could work. It's important to note however that the two fonts must be exactly the same or else it misfires.

Comment: @ChristopherCortez Monospace would also make it much easier!

Comment: Indeed. I've been trying to come up with a more robust solution using your code as the foundation, but am now running into cross-browser unreliability (not surprisingly).

Answer (score 2):

You can measure every line width using a "hidden" span.
If the line width is greater than the textarea width then the line is wrapped

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kbagz/3/)

```
function textWidth(txt, font, padding) {
    $span = $('<span></span>');
    $span.css({
        font:font,
        position:'absolute',
        top: -1000,
        left:-1000,
        padding:padding
    }).text(txt);
    $span.appendTo('body');
    return $span.width();
}
```