# Get textarea with line-breaks in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have to somehow split text from textarea by rows. It's not a problem when user hit `enter` on it because then in string is `\n` char so it's easy to detect.

But what if browser automatically move some word to another row in textarea? Is browser put some special char when sentence is split automatically?

```
var splitted = $('#textArea').val().split("\n");
```

Is not a soulution because it's work only when user hit `enter`.

Comment: I would check out this answer right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035910/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea/#answer-12927469

Comment: It's not a solution because it's not working when browser automatically split sentence in textarea.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429511/how-can-i-detect-when-a-line-is-automatically-wrapped-in-a-textarea#16429930), maybe other _workarounds_ (understand: **not** _solutions_) exist, but what you're looking for is not "line break", it's "word wrapping".