# Make textarea grow on word wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This seems like a simple thing that must be on the internet somewhere and I'm just searching for it wrong. I have a `textarea` HTML element which I'd like to cause it to grow (i.e. increase number of rows) whenever the input text wraps around. So the number of rows should always match the number of rows of input text (i.e. no scrolling necessary to view all the text). What I have so far looks something like this:

```
<textarea name="my-textarea" class="input" rows="1" style="width: 100%; resize: none;"></textarea>
```

I have jQuery available to me if necessary, so I don't need this to be a purely HTML/CSS solution. Is there a particular event that I can listen on that will help me identify when to add a row?

Comment: You can have a check here : > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429511/how-can-i-detect-when-a-line-is-automatically-wrapped-in-a-textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect when a line is automatically wrapped in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429511/how-can-i-detect-when-a-line-is-automatically-wrapped-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

Auto-resize textarea to fit the content would need some JS and there's a small plugin for exactly that, called [jQuery Auto Resize](https://j11y.io/demos/plugins/jQuery/autoresize.jquery.js).

You can then call the plugin like:

```
$('textarea').autoResize();
```